# How do you get Access to the NgControl from a ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

I am building a custom component, It implements the ControlValueAccessor so I can use it with ngControl and ngModel in my from. Now I would like the logic to validate the component to be within it self (so that it is self contained). So far so good, but now I have a **cyclic dependency** as I am trying to inject       NgControl (to set the external form state) within a component that inject it self a **CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR** provider. Here the code:

```
const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInput),
    multi: true
  });

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'custom-input',
  templateUrl: 'custom-input.html',
  styleUrls: ['custom-input.css'],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomInput implements ControlValueAccessor{

  private _text: any = '';
  public isValid:boolean = false;


  onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  onTouched: any;


  constructor(private ngControl:NgControl) {

  }

  onToggle(){
    this.isValid = !this.isValid;
    let res = this.isValid? null:{ "test": true };
    this.ngControl.control.setErrors(res);
  }

  get text(): any { return this._text; };

  set text(v: any) {
    if (v !== this._text) {
      this._text = v;
      this.onChange.emit(v);
    }
  }

  writeValue(v) {
    this.text = v;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn): void {
    this.onChange.subscribe(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}
```

how can I get a reference to the ngControl from within the component ? I know that you can do this: 
`this.ngControl = this._injector.get(NgControl, null);` but that kind of feel like a hack in this case doesn't it ?

Answer (score 6):

You can inject `NgControl` to your component.

```
constructor(@Self() @Optional() private ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
}
```

And remove `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` provider.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 DI can't deal with cyclic dependencies. That is a limitation of constructor injection Angular2 uses. Therefore you're stuck with the hack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I think you're trying to inject 'self' and that doesn't make much sense. I had similar problem and I solved it by creating external 
Validator directive, in which you can inject created ngControl.

```
@Directive({
selector: '[customValidate][ngModel],[customValidate][formControl]',
providers: [
    provide(NG_VALIDATORS, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomValidator),
        multi: true
    })
]})

export class CustomValidator {

validator: Function;

constructor() {
    this.validator = SOME_VALIDATION_FUNCTION;
}

validate(c: NgControl) {
    // use injected ngControl
    return this.validator(c);
}}
```

This approach works both when you have validation on component itself, or on some nested input you might use.

IMHO this is the 'correct' way, since it separates concerns between validation and logic in you component.